# Maximum network bandwidth for Azure File Share

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-files

What would be the best configuration of Azure VM and Azure File Share to get maximum network bandwidth between the two?

Can I do anything more than placing both in the same region?
Can Accelerated Networking be used in this scenario?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once you are going to consume your file share form an Azure VM, not from anywhere outside (internet). I would say you can consider 3 things, it is going to improve your performance and security. Just in case you should also verify if any other resources in your storage account can be affected after changing to private endpoint, please deep read all articles below about it.

1 - configure a private endpoint for your storage account where you have configure your file share, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-networking-endpoints?tabs=azure-portal)

2 - there is an option for networking accelarator as described into these [Web Site](https://www.360visibility.com/azure-accelerated-networking-and-how-to-enable-it/#:~:text=Azure%20Accelerated%20Networking%20is%20a,greatly%20improving%20its%20networking%20performance.&text=It%20will%20enable%20speeds%20of%20up%20to%2025Gbps%20per%20Virtual%20Machine.) and [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/create-vm-accelerated-networking-cli)

3 - some tips about size of VM, refer to [article1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-optimize-network-bandwidth), [article2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-machine-network-throughput) and this [test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-bandwidth-testing)